# Android multiple resource library projects

Tags: java, android, dependencies, android-library

I have several Android Applications, that use the same core project (services, activities, handles, etc). The difference between the apps is just the UI (colors, button resources, string) and the URL to the back-end server.

Currently I'm trying to refactor it and have an issue with project dependencies.

Here is the idea, I need to have several projects with resources (like png, color xmls, and strings) and one with layout and style xmls that will require one of these projects in the build path of the resulting app apk. Something like this:

```
- prj-build1 // First app
- prj-build2 // Second app
...
- prj-core // The core classes of the project
...
- prj-ui // UI and style xmls
- prj-res1 // Image and string resources for the build1
- prj-res2 // Image and string resources for the build2
```

Clearly all projects (except prj-build1 and prj-build2) are library projects. But I can't add prj-res1 or -res2 as libraries for prj-ui (only to the build projects).

Currently prj-ui show errors (it can't find image, string and color resources) and I don't have a clue how to solve this. How can I solve this dependency issue?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why don't you use the interface Build Path to create the dependencies ?

Comment: I tried to add prj-res1 as a "Required in build path" to prj-ui but the project still can't find the resources.

Comment: You re trying to add .jar ? Native code in java ?

Comment: The project is fully native android java code.
I'm trying to use 2 separate projects for image and string resources, the layout xmls are in a separate project.

Comment: Normally you would check the ohers project "is library" in properties and in the one where you want to use them you import them "as library"

Comment: I know that, but this is not the current problem... the projects that should be libraries are marked as libraries.

Comment: try Android Studio(i know that it's in preview version but ...) it using gradle... http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: I fought about that, but this is not an option for now.